# Calculate the flow of $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = 3x\vec{i} + 3y\vec{j} + z^5\vec{k}$ over the surface $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ for $0 \leq z \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

Calculate the flow of $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = 3x\vec{i} + 3y\vec{j} + z^5\vec{k}$ over the surface $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ for $0 \leq z \leq 1$. The normal considered points inside.

The book uses cylindrical coordinates and the final answer is $-150 \pi$. I want to see other ways to approach the problem so I could understand better the concept. Must we not use the jacobian in this case? How would I solve the problem with cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parametrize the surface  $S$, $\vec r=(x(t,s),y(t,s),z(t,s))$. An obvious choice is $y=t$, leading to $x=\pm\sqrt{25-t^2}$ and $z=s$ free:

$$\vec r=(\pm\sqrt{25-t^2}, t,s)\;;-5\leq t<5\;;0\leq s\leq 1$$

$\vec  F$ on the surface is $\vec F=(\pm3\sqrt{25-t^2},3t,s^5)$

Now, we need the expression for a vector for the surface element. We get it from the cross product of two vectors tangent to the surface:

$\dfrac{\partial \vec r}{\partial t}=\left(\dfrac{\mp t}{\sqrt{25-t^2}},1,0\right)$

$\dfrac{\partial \vec r}{\partial s}=(0,0,1)$

$\dfrac{\partial \vec r}{\partial t}\times\dfrac{\partial \vec r}{\partial s}=\left(1,\dfrac{\pm t}{\sqrt{25-t^2}},0\right)$

Then, the flux,

$$\Phi=\int_S\vec F·\left(\dfrac{\partial \vec r}{\partial t}\times\dfrac{\partial \vec r}{\partial s}\right)\;\mathbb d t\,\mathbb ds$$

$$\Phi=\int_{0}^1\int_{-5}^5\left(3\sqrt{25-t^2}+\dfrac{3t^2}{\sqrt{25-t^2}}\right)\,\mathbb d t\,\mathbb ds+\int_{0}^1\int_{5}^{-5}\left(-3\sqrt{25-t^2}-\dfrac{3t^2}{\sqrt{25-t^2}}\right)\,\mathbb d t\,\mathbb ds$$

$$\Phi=150\pi$$

My result is in positive because I've been using the pointing **outwards** vector for the surface element (and the field $\vec F$ points outwards too on the surface)

Comment: There are a lot of details to pay attention to when using cartesian coordinates! Thank you for the alternative solution. I have also noticed you didn't use jacobian and ended up with the same result. I think it is kind strange how different parameterizations give the same result without a factor to correct it. I guess the answer for this is in higher mathematics... although I have seen a deduction for the flux integral formula where the jacobian is canceled out.

Comment: We don't need the jacobian! we didn't change coordinates :) The, say, part of the jacobian the cylindrical coordinates have in cartesian is given directly from the surface element and the formula 8ninto the parametrization. And you can grasp the reason for your questions thinking geometrically, thinking of the invariant objects involved (like vectors).